# ngIf and [hidden] not working as intended with angular 5 and fxFlex Framework

Tags: javascript, html, angular, flexbox, angular5

Note: Below is an example of `ngIf` where the elements that are supposed to be hidden are invisible members of the row now, so they still take up space.

```html
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
      <div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index">
        <mat-slide-toggle *ngIf="i == 3" [id]="question.key" >  {{question.label}} </mat-slide-toggle>
      </div>  
    </div>
```

Note: Below is `[hidden]` which will do nothing when true.

```html
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
      <div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index">
        <mat-slide-toggle [hidden]="i == 3" [id]="question.key" >  {{question.label}} </mat-slide-toggle>
      </div>  
    </div>
```

Hi,

I am working on an angular 5 project and I am running into some weird functionality.

Typically in angularJS 1.x, `ng-if` would remove elements from the DOM completely. But, in angular 5, `ngIf`, keeps the elements in the DOM.

The next logical step would be to use `[hidden]` since it applies the `display:none` property. But, wait! If you have a display property on the element you are wishing to hide, that property overrides the `[hidden]`.

My question is, does angular 5 allow for removing elements from the DOM like ng-if on angular 1.x did without having to make a custom directive to handle it better than the framework as well as how to handle using `[hidden]` if the flex property on the element negates [hidden]'s effect?

[fxFlex Layouts](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

link to sandbox to test out 
[Stackblitz sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-seed?file=app%2Fcheckbox.group.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

When using fxFlex you can use fxHide to control the element's visibility:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [fxHide]="i == 3" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`*ngIf` is a structural directive and which means that it will not render the element in the DOM if the expression evaluates to false.

In your demo, if i put

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
      <div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index">
        <mat-slide-toggle *ngIf="i==3" [id]="question.key" >  {{question.label}} </mat-slide-toggle>
      </div>  
    </div>
```

Then only one toggle button is coming. Do inspect element and you will see that there are couple of

```
<div _ngcontent-c30="">
        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
      </div>
```

but these are just blank div containers without slide toggle button except the third one.

Comment: Yes, they are blank, but that is the problem since it's still in the DOM. The expected behavior I am looking for is that when the ngIf applies, it will bring the displayed element to the first position since the other elements are supposed to not be there.

This behavior I want can be solved with [hidden], but as I mentioned above, the flex display styles are overriding the display none css so it display ALL the elements even the hidden=true.

Comment: @Steve well that div is not because of *ngIf evaluating to false but is there because of *ngFor. So maybe you need to filter your array according to ngIf conditions before doing the *ngFor.